# Bayesian MCMC: use the burn-in phase to find an appropriate scale factor for the likelihood?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood

In a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366618/scale-log-likelihood-as-mcmc-sampler-advances-to-improve-acceptance-rate) I asked if I could scale the likelihood as my MCMC process advanced, to keep the acceptance fraction within a reasonable range (~0.2-0.5). I was told that this is **not** a valid approach, since doing that meant that the "*Markov chain is no longer time homogeneous*".

But, what if I used the burn-in stage to find an appropriate scale factor for my likelihood such that the acceptance fraction is reasonable? By "scale factor", I mean simply a real value that multiplies (and thus scales) my likelihood:

```
lkl_scaled = scale_factor * lkl_original
```

In this case I wouldn't be changing this factor during the MCMC process from which I later obtain the distributions of the model parameters. I would only do so during the burn-in phase, which I later discard.

I've tried this already and the results are excellent (where the chains get stuck forever with my original likelihood, they properly explore the parameters space with the scaled likelihood). I can't really see nothing wrong with this approach, but I'd like to be sure.

Is this a valid approach? If so, are there any caveats I should be aware of?

---

PD: I am aware of the existence of [parallel tempering MCMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_tempering), but this approach is far simpler and it allows me to use other MCMC methods that would otherwise be of no use since the acceptance fraction is generally below 1%.

Comment: You are no longer sampling from the posterior if you do this. You are sampling from a fractional posterior, which is more-or-less equivalent to throwing data away. If I throw all my data away, of course I can sample much more easily (say, just generating from the prior), but this is obviously not worth the price I would be paying.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If I define a more-or-less arbitrary likelihood for the problem at hand, what changes if I multiply it by some factor?

Comment: I can confirm I am not sampling from the prior because I am using uniform priors for all my parameters and the final distributions are exactly what one would expect for the problem being analyzed. There's no price being paid here, the opposite actually.

Comment: As I said, you are effectively tempering the likelihood, which is equivalent to using a fractional posterior. You are effectively throwing away 100 * scale percent of your data by doing this. If you want to know more about fractional posteriors then you can find that information easily, but suffice it to say most people don’t want to use fractional posteriors. The whole point of parallel tempering is to make use of the fact that fractional posteriors are easy to sample from to get you to samples from the thing you actually want.

Comment: "*You are effectively throwing away 100 * scale percent of your data*", I don't understand this. You mean that the smaller the scale, the lower the fraction of data I "throw away"? That doesn't make much sense. Apart form this, if I can effectively obtain **much** better results with this fractional posterior (fractional likelihood?), can I use this approach or is there anything inherently wrong with it (other than "throwing data away", which is a price I am more than willing to pay to actually obtain a result from the MCMC process)?

Comment: Sorry, not throwing away 100*scale, but keeping 100*scale percent. If your scale is equal to 1, you get the usual posterior. You say you get "better results", but it is impossible to conclude that this is true because you cannot sample from the actual posterior. You say it is better, but better relative to what? You cannot sample from the posterior, so how do you know the results from the fractional posterior are acceptable?

Comment: Because my problem involves fitting observed data to synthetic data (generated and then compared to my observed data through the likelihood) and I can see that the final parameter values correspond to a synthetic data set that match my observed data almost perfectly (and this is using a really small scale) And this is with *all uniform* priors.

Comment: To be more concrete about what the main potential concern here is - if the problem you are looking at is even moderately difficult, you will probably need to `scale` very small to get a good acceptance rate. By doing this, you will essentially be throwing away so much data that it is questionable whether or not the results you get from such a posterior will be anywhere close to what you would get with the genuine posterior.

Comment: I understand that but, as I explained above, I can actually check at the end of the process that the final parameters (their means, for example) are reasonable because they are associated to a synthetic data set that matches my observed data set almost perfectly (using uniform priors on all parameters) This isn't just a coincidence.

Comment: In that case, I suppose the question is whether or not you care about actually sampling from the posterior. If you want approximate samples from the posterior, the answer with regards to "is this approximately valid?" is **no**. If you don't care about actually sampling from the posterior, but have some other goal in mind, then your strategy may or may not be acceptable. I will say that the fractional posterior means, if you have non-informative priors, will be roughly OK on average, but the posterior variance of these parameters will most likely be greatly over-stated.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me guy. If I understand correctly, you say that the mean (median, mode) of  my parameters distributions will be mostly reasonable, but I couldn't really extract an uncertainty for my parameters (ie: a sigma, or 16th-84th percentiles)? I can see why this would be true, since the smaller the scale factor the flatter the final distributions hence the larger the standard deviations. Am I on the right track here? If so, could you put your comments in the form of an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Vis-a-vis my previous comment about the fractional posterior means being "roughly OK", this is also problem dependent. I can imagine there being issues in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give an idea for what the effect of doing this is, consider the following simple Gaussian model. 
$$
Y_i = \mu + \epsilon_i, \qquad \epsilon_i \sim N(0,1). 
$$
Suppose we put a flat prior on $\mu$. The genuine posterior in this case is $[\mu \mid Y_1, \ldots, Y_n] \sim N(\bar Y, n^{-1})$. Let's compare this to the posterior obtained from scaling the log-likelihood.
$$
\pi_c(\mu \mid \mathbf Y) 
\propto 
\left[\prod_{i = 1}^N e^{-(Y_i - \mu)^2 / 2}\right]^c
= \prod_{i = 1}^N e^{-c(Y_i - \mu)^2 / 2}. 
$$
By the usual argument, this leads to a Gaussian posterior for $\mu$ as well: 
$$
\mu \sim N(\bar Y, (cn)^{-1}).
$$

Now, what conclusions can we draw?

- We are certainly not drawing from the genuine posterior.
- *In this particular case*, the posterior mean turns out to be the same. This suggests that, for point estimation, there are *at least certain situations* in which scaling the log-likelihood does not lead to a disaster.
- The scale factor is weakening our precision, and essentially corresponds to the posterior "throwing data away." For example, setting $c = 0.5$ is sort of like using half of the data.
- This "throwing away data" idea does not affect the posterior mean in this case because we used a flat prior, but would have also impacted the posterior mean if we had used (say) $\mu \sim N(0,\tau)$; in particular, we would have gotten more shrinkage towards zero.
- Even though we - *for this particular example* - have still got the correct posterior mean, the posterior variance is off. So, if I take $c$ to be very small to improve mixing, I should expect to be artificially inflating the variance by a factor of $1/c$.

The main concern with using this approach, and tuning $c$ to get a good acceptance rate, is that you will need to take $c$ very small. This is guaranteed to mess up your posterior variance, and is likely (but, evidently, not guaranteed) to mess up the posterior mean as well.

A more subtle problem if you *do* have weakly-informative priors is that, as the sample size grows, you will probably need to take $c$ going to $0$ to maintain a reasonable acceptance rate. This will cause the bias induced by the use of a weakly-informative prior to never be washed away by the data, so viewing this approach by embedding it in a standard Frequentist asymptotic analysis suggests that you may end up with inconsistent estimates.

Comment: The only difference I see with this example and my approach is how the scaling factor is applied. In this example the likelihood is scaled to some power, which will alter its shape (to flat or 1 in the c=0 limit), while my scale factor is multiplied by the likelihood which only changes the scale and not the shape. Do the same arguments made in this answer apply regardless?

Comment: @Gabriel If you are multiplying the *likelihood* by a constant (and not the *log-likelihood* as I assumed) then you aren't actually doing anything. For example, all Metropolis-Hastings algorithms are invariant to multiplicative constants - this is what makes them useful, since the normalizing constant is an unknown multiplicative constant. The previous question you linked to has the scale factor coming in the log-likelihood, not the likelihood.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct and I am in fact multiplying the log-likelihood. I see where the power comes from now. Thank you for the extensive explanation guy!